# Error between intel HD and nvidia GPU same directx application same Feature Level

Tags: c#, directx, gpu, sharpdx

My application runs fine or as i want on my local development pc with a intel hd. I force the feature level(10_1) by device creation to be on the same than my target machine.

However, if i run it on my intel HD it is all fine and working, but crashes on the target after a while and behaves differently.
I added code that uses CopySubresourceRegion(...) to copy from one render target to another. this seems to behave diffrently already until it crashes. 
Maybe that has to do with the issue. I wonder thought, because i thought since i use the same runtime and feature level it should behave the same.

If my question is to general i can add specifics, but for now I am asking if you know what could cause that behavior and I am missing. I am still new to DirectX programming.

e: has this to do with threading?

Comment: First make sure you don't have any ERROR or CORRUPTION messages coming from the Direct3D debug device. Make sure you are checking all ``HRESULT`` values coming back from Direct3D calls. Once you've done that, see if there are newer drivers available as it could be a driver bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by remote debugging on my target with enabled debug layer.

The error was indeed caused by CopySubresourceRegion(...).
The error was in the output locally (intel hd) and remote (nvidia). But the
nvidia seems to behave differently when this error arises and crashed (removed).

This link also says something about CopyResourceRegion(...) and the undefined behavior that caused the issue:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/jj200584(v=vs.85).aspx

The fix was to simply handle the edge cases in my copy region parameters correct and not relying on the undefined behavior.

Thanks to Chuck Walbourn for hinting to solve the issue.